# ng-style's variable not updating to the view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to add 20 px to my loader bar each time a successful request is completed.  a staggered set of data coming from various apis. $on each successful request, **I would like to add 20 to `var progress`** unfortunally even tho the number is incrementing `$scope.progressWidth` will not update the view.  It stays static at `width: 0px`.  when i tried $scope.apply() it says digest is already happening.

HTML view:

```
<div class="loader" ng-style="progressWidth"></div>
```

js:

```
var progress = 0;

$scope.progressWidth = {
    'width': progress + 'px'
};

angular.forEach(['load::1', 'load::2', 'load::3', 'load::video'], function (value) {
    $scope.$on(value, function (event) {
        load = true;
        loaded.push(true);

        if (load === true ) {
            load = false;
            progress += 20;
        }

        if (loaded[0] === true && loaded[1] === true && loaded[2] == true && loaded[3]) {
            $scope.$broadcast('load::menu');
        }
    });
});
```

data:

```
$http.jsonp('http://filltext.com/?rows=10&delay=1&fname={firstName}&callback=JSON_CALLBACK').
        success(function(data){
            $scope.datas[0] = data;
            console.log($scope.datas);
            $scope.$emit('load::1');
    });

    $http.jsonp('http://filltext.com/?rows=10&delay=2&fname={firstName}&callback=JSON_CALLBACK').
        success(function(data){
            $scope.datas[1] = data;
            console.log($scope.datas);
            $scope.$emit('load::2');
    });

    $http.jsonp('http://filltext.com/?rows=10&delay=4&fname={firstName}&callback=JSON_CALLBACK').
        success(function(data){
            $scope.datas[2] = data;
            console.log($scope.datas);
            $scope.$emit('load::3');
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a watch on the progress variable and updating the progressWidth from it:

```
$scope.$watch('progress', function(value) {
    $scope.progressWidth = { 'width': value+ 'px' };
});
```

Also, make sure that progress is in the scope as well and always update it calling $scope.progress.